# Create D3js chart using data from MySql PHP JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, d3.js

Just a beginner with d3js charts. I am not able to generate a D3js chart. Here is my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .arc text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        text-anchor: middle;
        }

        .arc path {
            stroke: #fff;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var width = 600,
            height = 600,
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(200);

        var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 60)
            .innerRadius(radius - 40);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        d3.json("getdata.php", type, function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;

            var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

            g.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

            g.append("text")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
        });

        function type(d) {
            d.population = +d.population;
            return d;
        }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here I am getting data from php, getdata.php:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","androidtest");

$query = "SELECT * FROM charts";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

mysqli_close($conn);

if($rows > 0){
    $data = array();
    while (($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))!=null){
        $data[] = $r;
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

My database looks as follows, table name charts

```
-------------------------------
| age  |  population          |
-------------------------------
| <5   |  2704659             |
| 5-13 |  4499890             |
| 4-17 |  2159981             |
|18-24 |  3853788             |
|25-44 | 14106543             |
|46-64 |  8819342             |
| >65  |   612463             |
-------------------------------
```

On running index.php file, there is no error in Javascript in inspection window. It is appearing as blank.

After calling the d3.json("getdata.php"... I tried getting the result to console log, like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log("Testing");
```

No console log. BLANK.

I also run: getdata.php, It is returning the string:

```
[{"age":"<5","population":"2704659"},{"age":"5-13","population":"4499890"},{"age":"14-17","population":"2159981"},{"age":"18-24","population":"3853788"},{"age":"25-44","population":"14106543"},{"age":"46-64","population":"8819342"},{"age":">65","population":"612463"}]
```

Comment: Does the JSON return correctly?  I don't know `php` well but it seems odd to close your connection before looping your resultset.

Comment: Have you tried running your d3 with a test dataset? Do you know if you're retrieving the data? It's impossible to know where your problem is.

Comment: @mark yes, php is returning json string perfectly.

Comment: @james i tried running it with d3 test dataset. It was working fine.

Comment: After your d3.json call, do a console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) and update your question with the output.

Comment: @Mark I just updated the question.

Comment: In your call of d3.json, try to remove 'type' argument. According to the doc (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json), d3.json has only 2 arguments.